# Dockerized Django App - Login timeout connecting to SQL Server Database ODBC Driver 17

Tags: sql-server, docker, pyodbc, django-mssql, mssql-django

I'm trying to connect my Django application, running in a container, to a SQL Server.

I've read many different topics but none of the provided solutions works in my case, can you please help me with any suggestions or hint that you have?

If I run the Django app from my local machine everything works, but when I use the containerized version I get the error:

> ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

The configurations of the settings are the following, and they work on the non-containerized version:

```
    'secondary': {
        "ENGINE": "mssql",
        "HOST":"0.0.0.0,1433",
        "NAME": "db_name",
        "USER":  "sa",
        "PASSWORD": "pwd",
        "PORT": "",
        "OPTIONS": {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        }
    }
```

The Dockerfile I'm using is like:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.9

# Install ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - && \
    curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list && \
    apt-get update && \
    ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17


# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of your application code into the container
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

#RUN your Django application
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Aside... you may experience less issues by referencing the correct package sources, e.g.: if you `docker run -it --rm python:3.9 cat /etc/os-release` you'll notice that it's using Debian 12 (not Debian 10). I'd also suggest installing the `unixodbc` and `unixodbc-dev` packages **before** referencing the Microsoft repo because Microsoft has a nasty habit of breaking their versions of those packages on a random basis.

Comment: The default TCP port for connecting to SQL Server is actually 1433. Have you tried removing the `,1433` from `"HOST":"0.0.0.0,1433"`? If you have an instance listening on a non-default port you'd usually enter that port number in the `PORT` setting. Also, `0.0.0.0`... are you sure that works as a client? Normally you'd enter the domain name, host name or IP address of the listening SQL server here. e.g.: if you have SQL Server listening on the Docker host itself (such as a Windows version of SQL Server) you might use `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: Didn't you ask this exact question yesterday?

Comment: And you duplicated the content twice in this question?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks a ton! I simply changed the host from "localhost" to "host.docker.internal" and it worked!

Edit:
The sql server is running in a container in the dev environment.
I'll figure out if this solution works also in prod environment and reply here.

Comment: It probably won't work (reliably) in a production environment - the docs specifically call out `host.docker.internal` as being a feature specific to Docker Desktop edition. Ideally your containers would be in the same Docker network so they could just communicate among one another by using their `expose`d ports and the internal DNS names assigned to them.